# specify non-transparent color for missing data in Cartopy map

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I'm having trouble specifying a color for missing values when using Cartopy with matplotlib's pcolormesh to make a map. I'd like to make all the "nan" values be, say, gray instead of white/transparent. To do that, I tried to use the `set_bad` method of matplotlib colormaps, but this seems to break Cartopy. The problem triggers a UserWarning from Cartopy, but I don't know what the workaround is.

Here's an example that doesn't even have nan values, but shows the problem:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib as mpl
import cartopy
import sys
print(f"PYTHON: {sys.version}")  # PYTHON: 3.8.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan 29 2020, 15:06:10) [Clang 9.0.1 ]
print(f" xarray {xr.__version__}")  # xarray 0.14.1
print(f" numpy {np.__version__}")  # numpy 1.17.3
print(f" matplotlib {mpl.__version__}")  # matplotlib 3.1.2
print(f" cartopy {cartopy.__version__}")  # cartopy 0.17.0

# construct fake data:
sig = np.sin(np.radians(np.linspace(-90, 90, 192)))
sig = np.tile(sig, [288,1]).T
darr = xr.DataArray(sig, dims=("lat", "lon"), coords={"lat":np.linspace(-90, 90, 192), "lon":np.linspace(0,360,288)})
# darr.plot.pcolormesh()  # Looks fine.

# fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection":ccrs.PlateCarree()})
# lons, lats = np.meshgrid(darr['lon'], darr['lat'])
# ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, darr, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())  # Looks fine.

cm = plt.get_cmap("viridis")
cm.set_bad("gray")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection":ccrs.PlateCarree()})
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(darr['lon'], darr['lat'])
ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, darr, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())  # Right side of map is gray / userwarning triggered
```

the Userwarning is: "UserWarning: The colormap's 'bad' has been set, but in order to wrap pcolormesh across the map it must be fully transparent."

So the warning is clear, and the result is a map with half the data obscured. My question is how to work around this limitation of Cartopy?

Comment: Try the troubled line of code with `cm.set_bad( "gray", alpha=0 )`, the `alpha` parameter should fix your problem.

Comment: @swatchai -- This totally works!! Thank you. If you post as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the troubled line of code

```
cm.set_bad("gray")
```

with

```
cm.set_bad( "gray", alpha=0 )
```

the alpha parameter representing "fully transparent" should fix your problem.

Comment: Is it just me or does that not actually solve the problem as fully transparent gray just shows as white again?